# Regex to find dictionaries in string

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I'm trying to write a regex for the following situation.
I have a file with hundreds of dictionaries as string.

EG:

```
{'a':1'}
{{'a':1, 'b':2}{'c':3}}
{'a':4, 'b':6}
```

I read the file and `removed the newlines`. Now I'm trying `split` them `based on a regex`.

```
{'a':1'}{{'a':1, 'b':2}{'c':3}}{'a':4, 'b':6}
```

`re.split("({.*?})", str)`. This wouldn't work because the whole second dict wouldn't match. How can I write a regex that would match all the lines return a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Where s this data coming from? Also, is that single quote after `1` intentional? Thanks.

Comment: Your input data are malformed: `{{'a':1, 'b':2}{'c':3}}` is not valid Python syntax. If it's a single dictionary with nested dictionaries then it's missing keys and a comma, and if you treat it as two separate dictionaries then you have extra braces.

Comment: any chance your file is `json`?

Comment: Each line is a json response. Every response is written/appended to a file. I'mean trying to read the file and store each response in a dictionary hence trying to split the string into dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do:

```
(\{[^{}]+\})
# look for an opening {
# and anything that is not { or }
# as well as an ending }
```

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
rx = r'(\{[^{}]+\})'
string = "{'a':1'}{{'a':1, 'b':2}{'c':3}}{'a':4, 'b':6}"
matches = re.findall(rx, string)
print matches
# ["{'a':1'}", "{'a':1, 'b':2}", "{'c':3}", "{'a':4, 'b':6}"]
```

See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tV4rC1/1)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Python regular expressions are not able to handle nested structures by themselves.  you would have to do some looping or recursion separately.

However, you commented above that each line is a json response.  Why not use `json.loads()` on each line.

```
import json

with open('path_to_file', 'r') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
```

`data` is now a list of dictionaries.

Comment: The json.loads() will fail because some of the dictionaries don't have the right structure. I'm trying to split the string into dictionaries before I can do a json.loads().

Comment: So it _not_ json then.  Does the data have a well defined structure that can be parsed?  What is the expected output for your sample data?